# how to resize the width of subcaption

Tags: subcaption, width

I have two pictures and I'm using `\usepackage{subcaption}` to place them beside each other.  The output might look like the following .

[image]

The problem in the above picture is that it is difficult to read the description of each picture. My question is that is there a way to reduce the width of each subcaption?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{rose.png} 
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{fig:subim1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{rose.png}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{fig:subim2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Right now, the picture has a width of 90 percent linewidth. You could just as well make the outer minipages a bit smaller and do a full linewidth picture.

Comment: @Johannes_B, would you please elaborate a bit? I have changed the width and reduced the minipage size but still having same problem.

Comment: `\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,` same for the other subfigure, and between the minipages, a simple `hfill`.

Comment: Look into the package description, it is fully customizable. A possible solution is e.g. `\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=5pt}` which puts a margin, alternatively you could also use indent...

Comment: Nice pciture you got!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possible ways to choose from. The first is making the whole subfigure a bit smaller, which will also make the figure a little bit smaller. If that is undesired, just make the caption width a bit smaller. No matter which way you choose, it looks kind of odd without centering the picture.

[image: crocoSmallerSubfigure]

[image: crocoSmallerCapwidth]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,
        height=5cm]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,
        height=5cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \centering\captionsetup{width=.8\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{subfigure}% Ensure no space and avoid warning
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \centering\captionsetup{width=.8\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}%
        \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```